# How to retrieve google contact groups using url.?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-contacts-api, google-shared-contacts

I am retrieving contacts groups of users. I have to show groups by pagination.
So i am doing like this,

```
URL feedUrl1 = new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/"+userEmail+
 "/full/?xoauth_requestor_id"+userEmail+"&start-index=10&max-results=5");

 ContactGroupFeed resultFeed1 = contactService.getFeed(myQuery, ContactGroupFeed.class);
```

Above query showing results starting from 10 and showing all records.
It is not retrieving results based on `max-results`. 
Is there is any wrong in it? What is another option for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick testing, and the max-results parameter is working as intended.

I have total 6 contact groups.  Happy 1, Happy 2, Happy 3, Happy 4, Happy 5 and Happy 6.

This is the request I made:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/userEmail/full?start-index=1&max-results=5
```

In the response, I get the parameter `<openSearch:itemsPerPage>5</openSearch:itemsPerPage>`, and it is only showing Happy 1 - 5 in the result.

I think if you are using the oauth_requestor_id, the URL should looks like this:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/userEmail/full?xoauth_requestor_id=userEmail&start-index=10&max-results=5
```

Comment: I used the same url, but still giving me all records. start-index parameter is only working fine.But I am unable to get why max-results is not working. I am using contact API 3.0. Please replay.

Comment: I have to retrieve size of group.I haven't set start-index and max-results. By default it is giving me 25 contacts. Is there any other way to for knowing the size of contact group..?